# How to enable INNODB in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, innodb

When I execute a query in MySQL it returns an error saying that InnoDB is not enabled. When I clicked the storage engine, the InnoDB was disabled.

How do I enable InnoDB?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to enable it in `my.cnf` file, then restart your server:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb

Or you can load an InnoDB plugin during runtime:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/storage-engines.html#replacing-builtin-innodb

Comment: Do you also need to convert individual tables to use InnoDB if they were created when a different storage engine was default?

Answer (score 18):

I faced a similar situation where InnoDB got disabled after a mysql-server upgrade. The query "**show engines**" didn't display **Innodb**. Following [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,397052,408970) fixed the issue for me.

```
    /etc/init.d/mysql stop

    cd /var/lib/mysql/

    ls ib_logfile*
    mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.bak
    mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.bak

    /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: This fixed my issue finally! I spent hours going through a ton of different steps, but I couldn't get mysql to start and kept seeing errors related to ```Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)``` and removing these InnoDB log files was the fix!

Comment: This can also can cause *total loss* of peoples working database. So don't do this first, don't do `rm`, and look the the server error log, there are plenty of non-guesswork corrections to why InnoDB is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

In `my.ini` (located in MySQL folder) put a `#` sign before `'skip-innodb'` to disable this command. Then restart mysql. This will enable InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

If your InnoDB gets disabled after a mysql-server upgrade what you have to do Initially is to set **plugin-load** of  at server startup using

> [mysqld]
>
> plugin-load="myplugin_1=myplugin_1.so;myplugin_2=myplugin_2.so";

And then specify the pathname to the **plugin_dir**(plugin directory) it can be done by following changes in the **my.cnf** file

```
[mysqld]

ignore-builtin-innodb

plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so

plugin_dir=/path/to/plugin/directory
```