# Error in db connection in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please go through the link

http://amymcnamara.com/fortest.php

here this error is giving:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

why this error is giving??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38.

Comment: @RikeshShah That's a domain socket. Nothing to do with firewall.

Answer (score 1):

That means that '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' doesn't exist. The most probably, mysqld is down or utilizes another socket for accepting connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mysqld.sock file, which is generated by mysql when it is turned on.
Or just create empty file called 'mysqld.sock' in folder - /var/run/mysqld/

Answer (score 0):

This Error

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /nfs/c09/h01/mnt/130514/domains/amymcnamara.com/html/fortest.php on line 2
Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

usually occur when you give wrong domain name OR username OR Password for database connection so check your connection i think there's error.