# not able to connect to database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sockets, codeigniter

It was working fine, all of sudden my db connection stop working.
below is the dump i got.

```
Array
(
    [hostname] => localhost
    [username] => ****
    [password] => ****
    [database] => *******
    [dbdriver] => mysql
    [dbprefix] => 
    [pconnect] => 
    [db_debug] => 
    [cache_on] => 
    [cachedir] => 
    [char_set] => utf8
    [dbcollat] => utf8_general_ci
    [swap_pre] => 
    [autoinit] => 1
    [stricton] => 
)
```

Trying to connect to database: picspeak_dbCannot connect to the database because: `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'MySQL' (2)`

i don't know how to solve it, please help me

Comment: Is MySQL running? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38

Comment: i resolved it by using 127.0.0.1 as server instead of localhost , thanks to all