# What's the cause of this "PHP/MySQL Can't Connect Through Socket" error?

Tags: php, mysql

For two minutes today my users were seeing this error:

```
[03-Jul-2013 13:30:58] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

What's the cause of this? It randomly came and went just as quickly. It happened for a couple of minutes yesterday too. Is it my host's problem? Or a problem with my script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/90342-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8084959/342740)

Comment: What's the code of the script in question?

Comment: And... use mysqli. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: This is most certainly not a duplicate. The other question seems to imply that the user is having a persistent problem, where as this question is inquiring into the nature of a random lockout. I just ran into this problem today, and seeing this question being tossed aside like rotten cabbage irritates me greatly.