# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I recently installed packages MySQL client and MySQL server for Cygwin.

However i'm getting the above mentioned error,

**What i did:**

-- To start MySQL client:

```
mysql -u root -p password -h 127.0.0.1.
```

**What i observed:**

-- **Path to /var/run/mysql.sock doesn't exists.**

-- **There is no /etc/init.d/mysql script(to start MySQL server daemon mysqld).**

-- **I'm running with Windows Administrator account in cygwin. There is no root user of linux.**

-- **Executed mysqld_safe.exe to initiate mysql server. This failed to start.**

Please let me know the solution or whether i need to install additional packages.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "installed" does that mean "finished" or "successful"?

Comment: yes, what i can see is exe's like mysqladmin.exe, mysqlrepair.exe and others in my bin directory

Comment: I am asking if you successfully installed or just finished installed?

Comment: Yes it is a successful installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)