# Error Upgrading GitLab 6.1 to 6.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, gitlab

I want to update Gitlab (6.1 to 6.3) but after the Checkout this happens.

I update the database with the command:

```
ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

I need to know how to troubleshoot:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/home/gitlab/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Systeminfo:

- Ubuntu 12.10 64
- LTS Ruby 2.0,
- GitLab 6.1

---

The full output:

```
root@j72177:/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs# ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production 

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/home/gitlab/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:224:in `table_exists?'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `included'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:98:in `include'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:98:in `taggable_on'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:39:in `acts_as_taggable_on'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/app/models/issue.rb:38:in `<class:Issue>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/app/models/issue.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/lib/api/notes.rb:6:in `<class:Notes>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/lib/api/notes.rb:3:in `<module:API>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/lib/api/notes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/lib/api/api.rb:1:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/lib/api/api.rb:1:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/lib/api/api.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/initializers/2_app.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/initializers/2_app.rb:13:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/initializers/2_app.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
root@j72177:/home/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs#
```

Comment: `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/home/gitlab/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) `

Comment: What was the root cause of your error, since you selected my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check "[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '`/path/to/mysql.sock`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084959/6309)" for various common causes behind that error message.

That path is configured in your [`gitlab/config/database.yml.mysql`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/database.yml.mysql) file.

Mainly:

- check that your mysql is running (mysqladmin -u root -p status)
- check the access rights (`sudo chmod -R 755 /home/gitlab/mysql/tmp/mysql`)
- check your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- check [how/if you have installed `mysql-server`](http://community.bitnami.com/t/gitlab-6-install-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket/20728/15).

Also make sure you follow the [migration process](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/7101b22c2efac40d4454a887a602ff46288d66fc/doc/update/6.0-to-6.2.md#5-install-libs-migrations-etc):

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --without development test postgres --deployment
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```