# Creating a PDO connection string from PHP class and DBMS techniques

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

Here is my program description. I tried to create a Database connection class that has different method which differ in the way they pull the records from the database.

What I'm trying to do is -- setting the class attributes to the PDO connection parameters and creating a default constructor with those attributes. Whenever I need data, I will call those methods which are supposed to return records.

Question is : I suppose that my connection string for creating the PDO object is right, but It will show error saying **Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

Can you please help me out to figure out whats really going on ? 
And also can you please share with me the techniques and ideas to create secure, robust and dynamically accessible database classes or methods? I would highly appreciate. Thanks in advance!

**Code :**

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnection {

        private $hostname;
        private $dbname;
        private $username;
        private $password;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->hostname = "hostname";
            $this->dbname = "database";
            $this->username ="username";
            $this->password = "password";
        }

        function getDataFromTable($query){
            echo $dns;
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host = {$this->hostname} ; dbname = {$this->dbname}", $this->username, $this->password);
            // stuffs ...
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: can php not have constructor without parameters ? like java has ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear the whitespaces:

```
$db = new PDO(
    "mysql:host={$this->hostname};dbname={$this->dbname};charset=utf8", 
    $this->username,
    $this->password
);
```

With PHP >= 5.3.6 you can add the charset to the dsn. (`charset=utf8`)

Another possible problem: (http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

> When the host name is set to "localhost", then the connection to the server is made thru a domain socket. If PDO_MYSQL is compiled against libmysqlclient then the location of the socket file is at libmysqlclient's compiled in location. If PDO_MYSQL is compiled against mysqlnd a default socket can be set thru the pdo_mysql.default_socket setting.

So try with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` for the hostname or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38?answertab=active#tab-top).