# MySQL not starting on AMPPS 3.8 on iMac/OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, operating-system, webserver

I am running **AMPPS 3.8** on *OS X (Mojave v10.14)*

After my HD unexpectedly died, I replaced the HD and reloaded my latest backup. MySQL does not load/run in AMMPPS :( My expectation was that the AMPPS would work as expected (Apache/php 7.1/MySQL would all run per usual).

In attempting to resolve the issue I have read through the [AMPPS wiki](https://www.ampps.com/wiki/MySQL_is_Not_Running), youtube, googling, and [reading similar threads on stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291091/mysql-doesnt-starts-on-ampps-os-x#), I attempted the following steps as listed below. MySQL did not turn on when i clicked on the on/off butto, nor did clicking the restart cause MySQL to start.

**WHAT I ATTEMPTED:**
 1. Clicked on config icon: *This now opens 'my.cnf', not 'my.ini'*
 2. added instruction line to my.cnf:  *innodb_force_recovery = 1*
 3. Save configuration
 4. Clicked on/off switch (did nothing/Did not click/did not work)
 5. Clicked restart icon

My MySql did not start.

[image: Text]

OBSERVATION: when you click on the configuration tool (tool icon), it opens the file 'my.cnf' instead of 'my.ini'

mysql.err log

```
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-24 10:38:28 1417 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: Error: tablespace id is 1140 in the data dictionary
InnoDB: but in file ./test@002emarvelchampionsuniverse/ma_images.ibd it is 1155!
2020-02-24 10:38:28 b088c000  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2961752064 in file fil0fil.cc line 797
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
18:38:28 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 133617 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
0   mysqld                              0x00309dbe my_print_stacktrace + 46
1   mysqld                              0x00148c35 handle_fatal_signal + 758
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0xa7cd7b6e _sigtramp + 46
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0xa7b9162b abort + 133
5   mysqld                              0x00377605 _ZL18fil_node_open_fileP10fil_node_tP12fil_system_tP11fil_space_t + 100
6   mysqld                              0x003780ad _ZL23fil_node_prepare_for_ioP10fil_node_tP12fil_system_tP11fil_space_t + 147
7   mysqld                              0x0037bea3 _Z6fil_iombmmmmmPvS_ + 513
8   mysqld                              0x00354bf1 _ZL17buf_read_page_lowP7dberr_tbmmmmxm + 460
9   mysqld                              0x00355134 _Z13buf_read_pagemmm + 88
10  mysqld                              0x00346f06 _Z16buf_page_get_genmmmmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_t + 488
11  mysqld                              0x0033c88d _Z27btr_cur_search_to_nth_levelP12dict_index_tmPK8dtuple_tmmP9btr_cur_tmPKcmP5mtr_t + 1128
12  mysqld                              0x0042100b _ZL17btr_pcur_open_lowP12dict_index_tmPK8dtuple_tmmP10btr_pcur_tPKcmP5mtr_t + 119
13  mysqld                              0x0042117f _Z21row_search_on_row_refP10btr_pcur_tmPK12dict_table_tPK8dtuple_tP5mtr_t + 141
14  mysqld                              0x0041f64c _ZL25row_purge_reposition_pcurmP12purge_node_tP5mtr_t + 116
15  mysqld                              0x0041f73d _ZL34row_purge_remove_clust_if_poss_lowP12purge_node_tm + 194
16  mysqld                              0x004203d3 _Z14row_purge_stepP9que_thr_t + 478
17  mysqld                              0x003f9e0e _Z15que_run_threadsP9que_thr_t + 710
18  mysqld                              0x00443413 _Z9trx_purgemmb + 2971
19  mysqld                              0x00434bed _ZL12srv_do_purgemPm + 317
20  mysqld                              0x00435759 srv_purge_coordinator_thread + 1055
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0xa7cdf63c _pthread_body + 137
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0xa7ce2833 _pthread_start + 82
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0xa7cde806 thread_start + 34
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I am a barista who enjoys attempting to write apps for fun and to help keep my mind sharp with early on set Alzheimer's disease, at best I am a novice. I do this to exercise my mind in an attempt to hold on to as much as I can for as long as I can. I am hoping to get MySQL working again if only once to export my local db to preserve what I have done.

Thank you for any and all help.