# MySQLI connect to local server through socket error

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, mysqli

I am receiving the below MySQLI error when I try to connect to my DB:

`Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /nfs/c10/h03/mnt/144844/domains/trash.mysite.com/html/functions.php on line 43
Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

My connection file:

`<?php
    $host = 'internal-db.s144844.gridserver.com';
    $user = 'db144844_db';
    $password = '***********';
    $db = 'db144844_db';
?>`

The functions file:

`

```
require('connection.php');

function sendMessage($message)
{
    // this line loads the library 
    require('twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php'); 

    $account_sid = '***'; 
    $auth_token = '***'; 
    $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

    $client->account->messages->create(array( 
        'To' => "5555555555", 
        'From' => "+6666666666", 
        'Body' => $message, 

    ));
}

function resetTrash()
{
    //this could be set to just go on a certain day like tuesday
    $connection=mysqli_connect($host , $user , $password , $db);

    //turn alerts off in the db cause we missed it or whatever
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE trash SET done=0 WHERE id=1");

    mysqli_close($connection);

}

function markDone()
{
    //this could be set to just go on a certain day like tuesday
    $connection=mysqli_connect($host , $user , $password , $db);

    //turn alerts off in the db cause we missed it or whatever
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE trash SET done=1 WHERE id=1");

    mysqli_close($connection);

}
```

?>`

This is line `43` from the second function:

`$connection=mysqli_connect($host , $user , $password , $db);`

My host `MediaTemple` says that they can connect fine from their side using my connection info but a socket error seems like it would be something to do with `MySQL` not my code.

I can log into the DB fine using `phpMyAdmin` and such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: Your script is throwing several notices about undefined variables but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code properly without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply forgetting function parameters:

```
function resetTrash(){
    $connection=mysqli_connect($host , $user , $password , $db);
                               ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^
                                 ?       ?         ?        ?
```

You want:

```
function resetTrash($host, $user, $password, $db){
```

PHP can warn you about this errors. Please read about [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).