# Returning warning error

Tags: php, html, mysql

http://go.wlg.co.nz/login.php

I had a page working fine and I swear I didn't change anything. Now its returning this:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in
>   /home/content/93/10501493/html/go/connect.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/content/93/10501493/html/go/connect.php on line 16
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be
>   resource, boolean given in /home/content/93/10501493/html/go/login.php
>   on line 16
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be
>   resource, boolean given in /home/content/93/10501493/html/go/login.php
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/content/93/10501493/html/go/connect.php on line 18

Anything obvious jumps out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: Try using the local ip address (127.0.0.1) instead of 'localhost' in mysql_connect().

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mysql service is running

```
service mysqld start
```

Or

Are you connecting to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" ? when you connect to "localhost" the socket connector is used, but when you connect to "127.0.0.1" the TCP/IP connector is used. You could 
try using "127.0.0.1" if the socket connector is not enabled/working.