# Migrate::install is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, database-migration

I am newbie in **laravel** and trying to run `php artisan migrate:install` and got an **error**

```
[PDOException]                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I have modified app/config/local/database.php and app/config/database.php like -

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
        'default' => 'mysql',
    'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'laravel_db',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        )
```

Comment: [possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: @Supericy : But actual problem is not that. I have got the solution. Posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution.

Actual problem was that we have to **configure path** in **both** the **files** : 
`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`

```
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Open database.php in config folder if you are using laravel 4+ version and in mysql credentials change localhost to 127.0.0.1.

and if you are using laravel 5+ version then edit env file and change localhost to 127.0.0.1

that's how I solved this problem on my ubuntu (development machine).

Hope it will help.

Comment: Dear @user3284742 it fixed my issue.Thank You.