# MySql error after DigitalOcean backup (?)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, ubuntu-14.04

I have a site at example.com and it was fully functional using ubuntu 14.04 with Sentora CP untill saturday 11.07.2015 at 22:00

I am currently using DigitalOcean as my ISP.

After the time mentioned above, the MySql server stopped working, the only error i get now is:`#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I have tried different restores using the DO backup function, though this only takes me back in time and the database is critical to restore, i have fulla ccess to the server as root, and i have tried to download "/var/lib/mysql" and uploading again after restoring back to the backup taken 1 week before.

Currenly the only php running on example.com is a user login, account update info and other stuff you would normally see when logging into a site.

If anyone would be able to help me out it would be really much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: Sounds like maybe the MySQL server has stopped running. What's the output of `service mysql status` from the shell? Have you tried turning it off and on again (rebooting the droplet)?

Comment: The thread @Mihai linked to contains several other suggestions for how to identify and fix this problem. There's a number of potential reasons why mysql stops running.

Comment: @håken lid `service mysql status: mysql stop/waiting` when trying `service mysql start` i get this output: `start: job failed to start`

Comment: Try restarting it. Something like `sudo service mysql start`. If that doesn't work, check the mysql log files for an error message. The other thread contains more detailed suggestions.

Comment: @mihai, i get a different output on the error as i mentioned in my question: `#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: The path is a bit different but its the same error.