# Problems with mysql config - want to understand

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

i know that there are many questions which are connected with my question, but nothing helps me to come to my goal.

I'm on mac osx 10.10.4

in the past i had MAMMP installed on my mac. Later i deleted it to configure my local hosts by my own. In the meantime i use vagrant for this. But i want to understand how the local mysql config works.

My problem:
If i type "mysql -uroot" i get this error:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

The /Applications/MAMMP/.. folder are deleted and not there. So i think there must be a config file where this is inserted. But i cant find this file. Not in /etc/my.cnf and not in /usr/local/mysql/support-files/... nowhere...

Could anyone give me hints where my config for that is destroyed and how i can reapair it?
Would be great to hear from you guys. Thanks

Comment: Looks like your mysql server is not started.

Comment: no! this error says, that somewhere is configured that the sockets position is in /Applications/MAMP/... but how i discribed this folder not more exists. So i look for this conf file, did grep and something more, but this is nowhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: no, look on top "i know that there are many questions which are connected with my question, but nothing helps me to come to my goal."