# Unable to start MySQL

Tags: mysql, vagrant, ubuntu-12.04

I am using a virtual machine (ubuntu12.04) with Vagrant for development purposes. I had installed Apache, PHP and MySQL - which all originally worked. Now, MySQL seems to not work.

When I check the stasus by using `sudo service mysql status`:

```
mysql stop/waiting.
```

I tried to restart MySQL:

```
stop: Unknown instance
start: Job failed to start
```

While trying to connect via `mysql -u root -p`:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

I have gone through different questions related to this issue on this site but most solutions are referring to a memory space problem (which is not in my case).

Comment: `suddenly` ? you must have done something (change network conf, install new software ...) did you check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38) too

Comment: Is it possible your `mysql` install location changed, or the permissions on the folder changed?

Comment: I was testing my php page. It was working fine then I slightly modified my code and refreshed the url then such errors came. I am totally surprised the way it came the errors. As far new software, I did not nothing installed new software. 
I think my MySQL has been crashed