# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket but server is running

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I'm updating a site that I know has mySQL running, and I've installed a page that runs a MySQL query in the same form that the other, working queries on the page run.  Everything works locally, but on the live server I get a

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

error although I know sql is running, and other pages are successfully running queries on the same database/table with the same query syntax.  I don't have access to the root of the server, and shouldn't have to restart anything because I know mysql is running right?  Thanks a lot for suggestions

Comment: Is there a difference in configuration on local vs live?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: I don't think it can be a configuration issue because other code/queries in the same update are successfully running queries from same DB/table.  I wonder if its a permission issue or if maybe I'm trying to run a duplicate query or something?  This is my first program using php/mysql like this thanks for the help

Comment: " I wonder if its a permission issue or if maybe I'm trying to run a duplicate query or something?" No, the error message is quite unambigious. If it is a "permission problem" then it's because /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock is inaccessible.

Comment: But how do I troubleshoot this if I don't have access to the server root, and please understand that the *site is successfully serving other queries with the same parameters*  thank you