# Unable to connect to mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I have a Dockerfile that I am working on that pulls Mysql 5.6 and configures it (mostly with a bash and sql script). I am able to build and run it but when I try to connect to the database in the container I always get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have tried accessing the mysql database by using:

`mysql -u root -p`

`mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p`

I have tried everything I could think of and looked up articles on the internet but nothing works. Can someone tell me why? Here is my Dockerfile and bash script respectively:

```
FROM mysql:5.6

MAINTAINER Ryan K.
USER root

ADD mysqlAddUser.sh /tmp/
CMD ["/tmp/mysqlAddUser.sh"]
ADD foo.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/foo.sql

EXPOSE 3306

## Starting mysqld and running Database Scripts
CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATABASE_PASSWORD=test

/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
mysqladmin --login-path=local -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD"
mysqladmin password "$DATABASE_PASSWORD"

mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$DATABASE_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root'"
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')"
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''"
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\_%'"
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"

DB_ROOT_PASS=TEST
DB=portal

mysql --login-path=local -uroot -p"$DB_ROOT_PASS"
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASWORD" -e "CREATE DATABASE portal";
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "CREATE USER portaluser@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testing'";
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON portal.* TO portaluser@'localhost'";
mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES";

mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" $DB < /tmp/foo.sql
```

Comment: The socket is present in the container. If you are connecting from outside the container you have to provide the host with `-h` so that mysql can find your database.

Comment: I access it from within the container.. Basically run the container in /bin/bash and try to access the db from there using mysql -u root -p

Comment: Does the socket exist at that path in the container?

Comment: Last time I checked it didn't.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38

Comment: Some questions that will help debugging: Can you confirm you are using `docker exec` to get into the container and test? It is unclear if you are connecting locally from inside the container or externally. Can you post the `docker run` commands used to start the daemon and get into the container? Can you list `/var/run/mysqld/` to confirm that the socket actually exists? Can you post the `my.cnf` being used?

Comment: It's strange but actually I can't even build the container.

Comment: @AndyShinn I will look that stuff up once I get to work

Comment: @AndyShinn the mysql.sock file doesn't exist. Not sure of a way to view the contents of my.cnf since this is just a mysql container

Comment: Are you running two containers? I mean, first "docker run -d -it <your image>" and second "docker exec -it <first_container_name> bash" ; Well, I actually doubt that mysqld daemon had started.

Comment: No i am only running one container... I am grabbing the mysql container in my script and am trying to create the database and configure it

Comment: Also, I see an error in your dockerfile. There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect. You might want to use "RUN /tmp/mysqlAddUser.sh" instead of CMD ["/tmp/mysqlAddUser.sh"].  And in your bash script, you are calling /tmp/foo.sql (mysql -uroot -p"$DATABASE_PASSWORD" $DB < /tmp/foo.sql) but the file didn't exit in that location(you are copying foo.sql to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/foo.sql ) so the last line will fail.. Put the ADD foo.sql instruction before the RUN /tmp/mysq.. instruction and update your script

Comment: OK I will try that.. I actually realized that yesterday and did entry point instead

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with the same issue with mysql in a docker container. Sometimes I could connect with the mysql client, but more often not. Switched to mariadb and had the same problem.

What seems to have fixed it for me is to add some sleep commands in my scripts that create, start and destroy the docker containers. After commands like 'docker run' and 'docker stop' I added 'sleep 10' and that seems to help.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I actually found out why this was occurring.. The reason being is because i had an Ubuntu VM with only 1GB of Virtual ram allocated. That would most certainly cause issues especially if I had one container with Tomcat running.