# Can't connect to '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, sockets, raspbian, mysql-error-2002

This is my first post here, so I hope I do everything right and don't forget any important info. I'm glad for any hints, because I'm running out of ideas (if I ever had any ;)).

I am (or was) running owncloud on Raspbian Jessie (so I guess basically Debian). Suddenly owncloud stopped working. The nginx error points towards php5-fpm, further searches gave this error:

```
exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException' with message 'Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' in /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/db/connection.php:54
```

So it looks like a mysql error, and `/var/run/mysqld/` is actually empty.

Following these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) and
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38), I tried

```
sudo find / -type s
```

resulting in this output:

```
/run/php5-fpm.sock
/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
/run/thd.socket
/run/dhcpcd.unpriv.sock
/run/dhcpcd.sock
/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
/run/avahi-daemon/socket
/run/udev/control
/run/systemd/journal/syslog
/run/systemd/journal/socket
/run/systemd/journal/stdout
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
/run/systemd/shutdownd
/run/systemd/private
/run/systemd/notify
find: `/proc/30933/task/30933/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/30933/task/30933/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/30933/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/30933/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
```

In the processes with `top` on the other hand, mysqld and mysqld_safe show up.
mysql-client, mysql-server and php5-mysql are installed and updated to the latest versions.

I also had a look at

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

both show /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock as socket...

```
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf
```

mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) does not exist.

Additionally, it seems that I can't connect to mysql through

```
mysql -u user -p
```

at least it results in the Error 2002 as well.

Finally, I tried stopping and starting the mysql service. This resulted in the following output of

```
systemctl status mysql.service

mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2016-04-10 11:54:23 CEST; 23s ago
Process: 9777 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 12878 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

So I'm kind of lost what is going on, the problem occurs since some updates a few days ago. While writing this post, I went through all the steps again, just to be safe. At one point, I had a short glimpse at my owncloud instance in the browser, but then it was gone again. So I appreciate any help/hints!!!

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the issue: Can't connect to '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'. The problem was that mysql service was not started after installation. Once I run the following command, then it worked properly:

```
systemctl start mysql.service
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Nice! Helped :) Thank you )

Answer (score 0):

1.Activate log in .my.cnf

```
 log        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

Error logging goes to syslog. This is a Debian improvement :)

Here you can see queries with especially long duration

```
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

1. `$ ls -l /var/run/ | grep mysqld`
2. `$ ps -ef |grep mysql`
3. `tail -f  /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`
4. restart mysql
5. (option) delete socket & restart mysql

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer @Ronnin! I've added logging to my.cnf... The `tail` command gives /usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.44-0+deb8u1-log ((Raspbian)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
Restarting results in the same error as mentioned above with stopping and starting. How would I delete the socket? Sorry if I didn't understand your answer correctly!

Comment: first give here output from 1.,2.

Comment: 1. `drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql    root       40 Apr 10 13:18 mysqld` 
2. `root       612     1  2 12:07 ?        00:02:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe`
`mysql    10174   612 47 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306`
`pi       10192  3628  0 13:19 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql`

Comment: 1. stop mysq (1a. if stop produce error, killall mysql, again make shure that mysql not runinig with 1.,2.................after thaht  $rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid   and $ rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock........read http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/