# MySql fails log says cannot access /var/lib/mysql directory

Tags: mysql

I checked answers such as [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38) but the answers did not help.

I used `service mysqld start` to run while generating the log file.

When trying to set up and run mysql, I continue to get the error

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock'

When I check the log file in /var/log/mysql.log I get the InnoDB error mesaage

The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.

File name ./ibdata1

File operation call: 'open'.

Cannot continue operation

directory /var/mysql does exist. I changed the mode by hand to 777 just to make sure and the run changed it back to 755.

> drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql /var/lib/mysql
>   -rwxrwxrwx. mysql mysql ibdata1
>   -rwxrwxrwx. mysql mysql ib_logfile0
>   -rwxrwxrwx. mysql mysql ib_logfile1
>   drwxrwxrwx. mysql mysql mysql
>   srwxrwxrwx. mysql mysql shutdown (a DB I am trying to set up)
>   drwxrwxrwx. mysql mysql test

Other platforms in the system already have mysqld up and running and able to start or stop using `service`.

Comment: What is the permission and ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1` and its parents and siblings? You should post that as well.

Comment: @alvits all owned by mysql:mysql and rwx for all

Comment: What is the state of `SELINUX`? Run `getenforce` to check it.

Comment: @alvits Thanks that was the answer.  `setenforce Permissive` caused it to work. I compared it to the platform on which it was running and it was disabled there. Make this an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I posted my answer. I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `SELINUX` is enforcing, all processes are subject to context evaluation.

There are several ways to resolve this issue.

1. Create `selinux` policy to allow `mysqld` to open the necessary files and allow to listen on certain ports. This is not an easy task but there are resources avilable to get this done.
2. Set `selinux` to `permissive`. This will allow `mysql` to run. This will also generate audit messages from `selinux` which you can use to generate the policy for `mysql`.
3. Set `selinux` to disabled. This is insecure but acceptable when the database host is in a secure environment.