# Can't find mysqld.sock: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

### I've just registered to Stack Overflow because I really can't get out of this problem since 2 days ago. I use Xampp.

So, I'm following this Laravel [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/4?autoplay=true) and when from the terminal I type in the project directory or every elsewhere directory ***mysql*** or ***mysql -uroot -p*** it gives me this error:

***Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")***

I have mariadb that I've installed from https://mariadb.org/

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ( here I typed lsb_release -a )
**No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial**

By doing **cd /var/run/** and then **ll** I discovered that the directory **/var/run/mysqld** doesn't exist, and the mysql.sock file neither.

So I googled a bit and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38) where they talk about the **/etc/my.cnf** file but I discovered by doing some **cd** commands that I don't have even this file. ( But I've just noticed that I have a **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** and **/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback** file )

Anithing else ? Oh, yes. Uninstalling mariadb and installing mysql would not resolve the problem because I have issues with the dpkg packages.

I also tried a lot of times installing and uninstalling xamp, laravel dir, mysql, mariadb...

I don't really know what to do. :(((

Comment: What is in /var/log/mysql/error.log or /var/log/mariadb/error.log?

Comment: @ElvisPlesky I don't know where to start from, there are thousands of raws. Maybe this(?):

Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
[Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
Aborting **It seems that it gives error only until 23jul even if I typed mysql today too**

Comment: So here is the reason. Something else listens on port 3306. Find what with netstat -ntpl | grep 3306

Comment: **alessio@E1-510:/opt/lampp$ sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 3306**
[sudo] password di alessio: 
**tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      17999/mysqld**

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. However I still can't undertstand why I miss that two files ( **/etc/my.cnf** and  **/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock** )  and even if I want to create them from myself, I don't know what should I write inside them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! 
So, first I removed every trace of MariaDB with these commands:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

Then I reinstalled it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Now mariaDB works. However I still have problems with xampp because his Mysql database has a conflict with my mariaDB. So I changed the Xampp Mysql port from 3306 to 3308 and all works fine.