# Python's sqlalchemy on Google CLoud SQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance with `sqlalchemy` in order to use the Pandas `to_sql` function. My instance has an internal IP Address.

I got the following to work:

```
import MySQLdb

def get_con():
    return MySQLdb.connect(host='<IP Address>', user='root')
```

However when I use sqlalchemy:

```
import sqlalchemy

def get_con():
    s = 'mysql://root@<IP Address>'
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(s)
    return engine.connect()
```

I get the following error:

> `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, 'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\' (2 "No such file or directory")')`

Comment: A few ideas of what might be going wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38

Comment: This is a reference to running MySQL locally. I’m running it remotely on Cloud SQL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what MySQL driver you're using, but I'd guess it's [`mysql-python`](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) which hasn't been updated in four years. I'd recommend using a different driver.

I tried this using [`mysql-connector-python`](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) and this works as expected:

```
import sqlalchemy

s = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root@<IP Address>/<DB Name>"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(s)
engine.connect()
```

Same with [`PyMySQL`](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/)

```
import sqlalchemy

s = "mysql+pymysql://root@<IP Address>/<DB Name>"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(s)
engine.connect()
```

Also make sure you're specifying the database name here, it's missing from your example.