# Django + XAMPP on Mac (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Tags: php, mysql, django, xampp, xampp-vm

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6esTdOLXh4) tutorial to build a Django app with MySQL.

I am using XAMPP-VM for Mac. I set up my Database settings for Django as so:

```html
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8080',
    }
}
```

And I have started MySQL on XAMPP but when I run python manage.py migrate I get:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not...

Answer (score 1):

Just change `HOST` from `localhost` to the ip `127.0.0.1`. This will resolve your problem.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8080',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql client tries to connect through the /tmp/mysql.sock by default. You just have to point it to XAMPP's socket with a symbolic link.

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing your HOST from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'. This usually rectifies it on my end.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '8080',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in mysql latest version, so I downgraded to mysql 5.7.0 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to XAMPP-VM being installed and not the local XAMPP. Uninstall XAMPP-VM and install XAMPP.