# Can't connect to localhost using mysql

Tags: mysql, django, sockets

I am new to Django and mysql and I am trying to configure my django application's backend to mysql. I am using XAMPP for my local mysql database and anaconda as my pkg manager. Also using a conda virtualenv.

When I go to run `python3 manage.py migrate`, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)")
```

My database is setup as the following:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'exampleproject',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

I changed 'HOST' to 'localhost' but then get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you use Windows or MacOS?

Comment: I use MacOS Mojave

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084959/7764309

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find your `mysqld.sock` file location then add it to `HOST`
using xampp on Linux `mysqld.sock` file is in another location, therefore, it is not working for `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : '',
        'HOST' : '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'PORT' : ''
    }
}
```

Or 
Run MySQL server first then execute MySQL.

```
$ mysql.server start

$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Comment: I went ahead and did some digging to find mysql.sock and found it at this path: `/Users/aharr/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/var/mysql`


Now running into this error: 

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Users/aharr/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (61)")`

Comment: I found my.cnf file and was wondering if I should change `socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` equal to the pathway above?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I installed XAMPP-VM which wouldn't let me directly access the socket since I had to mount an NFS mount. Downloaded regular XAMPP and pointed it to the mysql.sock in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Thanks, I appreciate it !