# mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

I'm trying to export my wordpress database with `php wp-cli.phar db export` but I get this error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" when trying to connect
```

After looking for answer I've tried to start mysql.service with `sudo systemctl start mysql` but it isn't found

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

I also tried to start mariadb.service with `sudo systemctl start mariadb` but it wouldn't work

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I can't find answer on how to solve these errors can someone help me ?

Comment: is there a cause why you don't use https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/export/

Comment: I do use this actually

Comment: and this gives the socket messsage?

Comment: Yes each command that as to do with mysql return this error.

Comment: Check in your my.cnf File if socket is defined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38