# Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, amazon-web-services

My WordPress site ( http://steamboatperinatalconference.com ) just recently started going down and spitting this error

```
" Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1568 "
```

I have checked the db password and its ok, also reset the instance and sql server and both are running, I'm able to connect to my database through mysqlworkbench.

Not sure why my website won't display if the database is up and running.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is your wordpress site hosted? On EC2 isntance?

Comment: @junedAhsan yes EC2

Comment: Has your EC2 instance got a new IP due to machine restart or something else?

Comment: @junedAhsan Shouldn't. im still able to connect to the instance with FTP

Answer (score 0):

First kill the processes with:

`sudo pkill mysql`

and

`sudo pkill mysqld`

restart mysql

`sudo service mysql restart`

now you should be able to log in

`mysql -u root -p`

Comment: tried this, im getting this error

 InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38
Try this

Comment: tried it all, turns out I needed to sudo yum update

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in order to fix the issue I was having I needed to run a sudo yum update on the AWS ec2 instance, after performing the update the page was back up and running

Answer (score -1):

my.cnf (location of file /etc/mysql/ folder) configured with

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

check for MySQL is running with the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

changing permission to MySQL folder. If you are working locally, you can try:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```