# MySQL accessible from my machine but not from another machine on the same LAN

Tags: mysql, macos

I have MySQL running on an Apple OS X 10.14 machine. I use MailSteward Pro to access it, and it works fine locally from that machine. From another machine on the same LAN, which can ping the SQL server machine just fine, I get this error:

> Failed to connect to server: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I am not specifying a different .sock file on the connection on the MySQL server machine. What am I doing wrong - how to debug this?

Comment: That's the default when you don't specify a hostname, or use `localhost`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: You need to use `mysql -h "name or address of machine with MySQL"`

Comment: @Luuk That's for a different problem where the server is located on the same machine.

Comment: ok I checked my.conf and I see:   # Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1                            - does this line somehow restrict access only to localhost?

Comment: I did the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' and now I see: "Failed to connect to server: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.1.3' (61)" - how to debug - how do I tell where it's going wrong?