# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket (without using sudo)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, wsl-2

I am running Windows 10 Build 1904.1706 and Ubuntu 20.04 through WSL2 version 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2.

I am trying to install mysql (something I have done plenty of times before on regular linux machines) and I am running into some issues logging into MySQL using both the root account and a user I have created.

When I try to connect to the database using `mysql -u root -p` OR `mysql -u root`, I am given the following error:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)`

I have ruled out it being me connecting from the wrong host, since I have run an `ALTER USER` command to change root's host from 'localhost' to '%'. I get the same error when connecting as the user account I've created.

However, I can connect fine if I prepend `mysql -u root -p` with `sudo`.

Finally I have also tried to modify `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and changed the `bind-address` field to `0.0.0.0` and that made no change in behavior.

On all of my other MySQL installations I have experience with, I never need to use `sudo` to log into mysql as a valid user, so I am wondering if WSL2 is playing a role.

Edit: To add, when I am trying to connect to my MySQL server, I am doing so from within the WSL terminal and NOT a Windows terminal like Powershell.

I saw [another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38?rq=1) that suggested to CHMOD the `/var/lib/mysql` directory recursively, but that made no difference as well

Comment: What do you see from `ls -lh /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` with and without `sudo`? Does the MySQL installation on WSL put root-only protection on that socket / named pipe?

Comment: Perhaps that's the issue. I have no permission to read that directory. Edit: The parent directory /var/run/mysqld is owned by the mysql user

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else with this issue, you can connect to MySQL without sudo by appending the `--protocol=tcp` flag to your mysql command.

Ex.  `mysql -u root -p --protocol=tcp`