# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)")

Tags: mysql, django, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mysql-python

the ERROR above I became in the tutorial lesson 'The Ultimate Django 3' of Mosh Hamedani. Lesson part: Running Background Tasks, 5-Celery and Windows.
If you followed the pdf instruction and got no error, and lastly you had to run 'python manage.py migrate', maybe you got ERROR above.
I wanna share the solution here and it`s so simple ). I am grateful to nicholas.allarick, it was his solution in codewithmosh forum.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While we appreciate you sharing this - Remember to search for existing related questions as well.  Your answer is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339695/11810933) to the linked duplicate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your settings.py, then change the DATABASE configurations of HOST to ‘127.0.0.1’ instead of ‘localhost’.

[image]