# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in MAC M2

Tags: mysql, macos

I am not able to run mysql.
I get the error when I try to run `mysql -u root -p`

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

And when I try to `sudo mysql.server start` I got another error.

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.pid).
```

I tried completely removing and reinstalling `mysql@8.0.33` and `mysql@5.7` many time.

attaching some log

```
2023-07-26T19:33:30.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.err'.
2023-07-26T19:33:30.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2023-07-26T19:33:30.321526Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 61538
2023-07-26T19:33:30.322613Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-07-26T19:33:30.322621Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-07-26T19:33:30.322658Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-26T19:33:30.322729Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-07-26T19:33:30.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.pid ended
2023-07-26T19:33:40.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.err'.
2023-07-26T19:33:40.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2023-07-26T19:33:40.600285Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 61645
2023-07-26T19:33:40.601389Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-07-26T19:33:40.601396Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-07-26T19:33:40.601435Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-26T19:33:40.601505Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-07-26T19:33:40.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.pid ended
2023-07-26T19:33:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.err'.
2023-07-26T19:33:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2023-07-26T19:33:50.880612Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 61751
2023-07-26T19:33:50.881695Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-07-26T19:33:50.881707Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-07-26T19:33:50.881740Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-26T19:33:50.881814Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-07-26T19:33:50.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/RFL723.local.pid ended
```

Current OS: 13.5 (22G74) Mac M2

Comment: Check the MySQL server logs for details.

Comment: Just to keep it straight, we have an M2 processor Mac running a linux shell that is running mysql?  Can you connect to localhost directly and perhaps its just the socket that is derped?

Comment: Yes @easleyfixed

Comment: Ok as a test can you try to connect using MySQL Workbench to connect to it ?
Download here --> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: And also curious if this post has info that would help you ? -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38

Comment: You shouldn't be starting manually via `mysql.server` if you've installed via Homebrew. This should be managed via `brew services` which is a wrapper around  `launchctl`.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates you're running mysql with the wrong permissions.

How did you start your mysql instance?

A recommended way to install and manage mysql in mac is using brew

```
brew install mysql
brew services start mysql


mysql -u root -p
```

make sure that this is the correct instance you're running `which mysql`

The error in running it as sudo implies you're lacking permissions to create the pid file needed to run the process, due to a permission issue.

I'd try the brew repair utility `brew doctor`

or

```
sudo chown -R _mysql /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
```

which should allow the mysql user to write the PID process into that directory.