# InnoDB Error in Mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

Last night the server was upgraded from a MySQL server with InnoDB Cpanel have much of a problem when MySQL server will shut down!
Because many of the sites on vps in their database to InnoDB Engine Table Does not have put up their site and say

```
error: Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
```

Error

It will enable the mysql server but it did not put the InnoDB!
The mysql command

```
show engines;
```

I noticed the following result which is not InnoDB Result

```
mysql> show engines;

 | Engine | Support | Comment | Transactions | XA | Savepoints |

 | MyISAM | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance | NO | NO | NO |
 | MRG_MYISAM | YES | Collection of identical MyISAM tables | NO | NO | NO |
 | BLACKHOLE | YES | / dev / null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO | NO | NO |
 | CSV | YES | CSV storage engine | NO | NO | NO |
 | MEMORY | YES | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables | NO | NO | NO |
 | FEDERATED | NO | Federated MySQL storage engine | NULL | NULL | NULL |
 | ARCHIVE | YES | Archive storage engine | NO | NO | NO |

 7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Log into mysql server gives an error ...

```
121105 18:26:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from / var / lib / mysql
 121105 18:26:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 121105 18:26:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
 121105 18:26:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 268435456 bytes
 InnoDB: than specified in the. Cnf file 0 536870912 bytes!
 121105 18:26:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 121105 18:26:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
 121105 18:26:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
 121105 18:26:50 [Note] / usr / sbin / mysqld: ready for connections.
 Version: '5 .1.65-cll 'socket:' / var / lib / mysql / mysql.sock 'port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

in my.cnf innodb settings for both are:

```
 innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
 innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
 innodb_log_file_size = 512M
```

Thanks, plz help me to solve the problem.

Comment: If you have your friends to help solve the problem, why do you ask here? `:P`

Comment: Maybe this post wil help you: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757589/how-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql[/link]

Comment: @GregD , I checked out the work, but there is a problem.

Answer (score 6):

From what i see in your logs your *InnoDB* is broken due to its file `ib_logfile0`is  messed up. I had same problem when hard drive crashed leaving this file unreadable - after reading what i could form the broken drive file was good but data inside was messed out.

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 268435456 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the. Cnf file 0 536870912 bytes!
```

There it is -> You file is 256 mb size yet your configuration tells it should be 512mb size. Fix the error in the configuration.

Then - backup all yours data (innodb tables with data).
Shutdown database (clean shutdown - all transactions must be finished - the log shouldn't contain them in order to make the file bigger).
Then backup the `ib*` file and change configuration.
Restart DB.

For more detailed information go there http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html