# MySQL:How do I enable innoDB?

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL for a while, but now I found I need to use `InnoDB` engine, but there's no such engine yet:

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                   | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance    | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I found MySQL has `InnoDB`'s libs in its plugin dir:

```
root@AY130703163117124510Z plugin]# ls
ha_archive.a         ha_blackhole.la        ha_example.so        ha_federated.so.0      ha_innodb_plugin.so        libdaemon_example.a         mypluglib.la
ha_archive.la        ha_blackhole.so        ha_example.so.0      ha_federated.so.0.0.0  ha_innodb_plugin.so.0      libdaemon_example.la        mypluglib.so
ha_archive.so        ha_blackhole.so.0      ha_example.so.0.0.0  ha_innodb.a            ha_innodb_plugin.so.0.0.0  libdaemon_example.so        mypluglib.so.0
ha_archive.so.0      ha_blackhole.so.0.0.0  ha_federated.a       ha_innodb.la           ha_innodb.so               libdaemon_example.so.0      mypluglib.so.0.0.0
ha_archive.so.0.0.0  ha_example.a           ha_federated.la      ha_innodb_plugin.a     ha_innodb.so.0             libdaemon_example.so.0.0.0
ha_blackhole.a       ha_example.la          ha_federated.so      ha_innodb_plugin.la    ha_innodb.so.0.0.0         mypluglib.a
[root@AY130703163117124510Z plugin]#
```

I don't want to meet any uncertain problem, so how do I make `InnoDB` enabled ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable INNODB in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757589/how-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql)

Comment: @IswantoSan I don't see any `skip-innodb` in `my.cnf`, I think MySQL doesn't even load it, so I want to know how to make it loaded.

Answer (score 1):

go to my.cnf file,from there u can enable it.after finishing restart your server:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb

Or you can load an InnoDB plugin during runtime:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html

go through the following link

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-configuration.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757589/how-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql
```

Comment: How can I exactly `enable it` ? I didn't find any option about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are few more link for installation and configuration:
For installation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-installation.html

Configuring Innodb:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html

Comment: I don't quite understand, I find `innodb` plugin in its installation dir, is that mean I have already installed it ?