# MYSQL Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled

Tags: innodb

I get this error and the plugin InnobDB is DISABLED.

```
"
140315 17:09:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

140315 17:09:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

140315 17:09:07 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.

140315 17:09:07 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

140315 17:09:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
"
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable INNODB in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757589/how-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable it in `my.cnf file`, then restart your server.
Refer out this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb)

To load an InnoDB plugin during runtime you can go on to this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following error had occured because of  error in your code is being generated by the shared object **.so** file you have created

> 140315 17:09:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

So what i would reccomend you is to check your code and then automatically 'InnoDB' Plugin will be enabled